# Can I use jQuery .trigger() with event listeners added with addEventListener()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

In my (javascript, jQuery) code, I use two ways of firing events

```
jQuery('body').trigger('crazy-trigger-event');
jQuery("body").get(0).dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("crazy-dispatch-event"));
```

In the snippet here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jts9jhbt/3/

I have registered for custom events using both jQuery .on() and the DOM .addEventListener() methods.

Then I fire the events using both jQuery .trigger() and DOM .dispatchEvent() methods.

It seems like the listeners registered using .on() receive events fired both ways.

But the listeners registered with .addEventListener() only receive events fired using .dispatchEvent().

My use case is that I have a mix of legacy code and jQuery code, and it seems like it's safest to use .dispatchEvent() so that it's compatible with both.

So is there some change to the code I can make so that listeners registered with .addEventListener() can recieve events from .trigger() ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Simple Answer

**No**, you can't.

## Explanation

The main reason is that jQuery needs to work across multiple browsers and ...

> "[...] **jQuery's** event system **is a layer on top** of the DOM event system."

Eventhough there are exceptions, there is no efficient way for jQuery to know which events are supported by the browser currently due to *the lack* of a `getEventListeners` method.
The developers think that the creation of a solution

> "[...] **isn't possible** to do without **breaking existing code** or causing **performance issues**."

If that sounds like a challenge to anybody, you are free to prove them wrong by posting your solution.

---

The detailed explanation can be found in [Dave Methvin](https://github.com/dmethvin)'s answers to [jQuery's issue #2476](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2476).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to click on an event that scrolls a navbar on mobile and this worked for me:

```
 let targetElement = document.querySelector(".className");
 let clickEvent = new Event('click');
 targetElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

Comment: Hi @Marian Marian, it seems your answer does not relate to the question. The question is about getting compatibility between jQuery's .trigger() method and JavaScript's .addEventListener() method.